# How can I implement a toggle functionality in ReactJS where clicking a function reveals a menu, and clicking outside the menu hides it?

Tags: html, reactjs, react-hooks, tailwind-css

when I click a button the menu will come & in 2nd click or clicking outside the menu will hide. how can I do this using react.Js, useRef()?

I tried & the result showed me that, when I click the menu part or the button, the menu come out but when I click outside it doesn't unhide. t unhide I have to click on that specific button or something. I want when I click the button it will show and when I click another in that button or click anywhere in the webpage it will hide.

Comment: "*tried & the result showed me that,*" - Please add enough code to create a [mre]. [ask]

Comment: Repharase Question with "How can I implement a toggle functionality in ReactJS where clicking a function reveals a menu, and clicking outside the menu hides it?"

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To toggle, first use the `useRef` hook to create a reference to the dropdown div. After that use the `useEffect` hook to add an event listener for clicks outside the dropdown. On click of outside the dropdown, it checks if the clicked element is inside the dropdown using the `contains` method. If not, it closes the dropdown.

The `handleToggle` toggles the dropdown's visibility when the button is clicked.

Here's the implementation:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";

function App() {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
  const dropdownRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleClickOutside = (event) => {
      if (dropdownRef.current && !dropdownRef.current.contains(event.target)) {
        setIsOpen(false);
      }
    };

    // Add event listener to handle clicks outside the dropdown
    document.addEventListener("mousedown", handleClickOutside);

    // Clean up the event listener on component unmount
    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener("mousedown", handleClickOutside);
    };
  }, []);

  const handleToggle = () => {
    setIsOpen((prev) => !prev);
  };

  return (
    <div ref={dropdownRef} className="dropdown">
      <button onClick={handleToggle}>Toggle Dropdown</button>
      {isOpen && (
        <div className="dropdown-content">
          {/* Dropdown content goes here */}
          <p>Dropdown content goes here</p>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Did you create this answer with [ChatGPT](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-generative-ai-e-g-chatgpt-is-banned?cb=1)?